# Search Twitter API for tweets. Save and clean them up to a new txt file

Tags: python

I'm trying to get the below done, but keep getting an error. I know that I'm getting the information from Twitter because my monthly usage increasing. Any help would be appreciated.

Search Twitter for 5000 tweets mentioning the hashtag #covid and store them in a file titled `tweets.txt`. You should clean the tweets and make sure that one tweet is stored per line in the file, i.e. the `tweets.txt` file should exactly have 5000 lines (this can be done by replacing `\n` in the tweet text with a “ ”).

This is what I have so far:

```
import tweepy

API_KEY = “My key will be here.”

client = tweepy.Client(API_KEY)

query = "covid"

response = client.search_recent_tweets(query)


for tweet in tweepy.Paginator(client.search_recent_tweets, query=query, max_results=10).flatten(limit=5000):
   
  save_file = open('tweets.txt', 'w')
  for tweet in tweepy:
    tweet = tweet.strip()
    save_file.write(tweet + ' ')
    
print(tweet)

save_file.close()
```

Comment: BTW: you shoud open file before `for`-loops because opening with mode `w` automatically remove previous content. If you want to use it inside for`-loop then you would have to use mode `a` (append). And if you open inside `for`-loop then you should also `close` inside this `for`-loop but you close it after all `for`-loop

Comment: why do you use two `for`-loops ? Why do you first run `for tweet in tweepy.Paginator(...)` and later similar `for tweet in tweepy:`? maybe second loop should be `for item in tweet:` ?

Comment: You shouldn't be running `save_file = open('tweets.txt', 'w')` more than once.

Comment: My apologies sir. I'm a complete rookie (first every post). I'll do better next time.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show error message so I can only guess what can make problem.

You shouldn't use `for tweet in tweepy:` but directy `tweet.text`

```
# --- before loop ---

save_file = open('tweets.txt', 'w')

# --- loop ---

for tweet in tweepy.Paginator(client.search_recent_tweets, query=query, max_results=10).flatten(limit=5000):

    item = tweet.text.strip().replace('\n', ' ')

    save_file.write(item + '\n')

    print(item)

# --- after loop ---

save_file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this to be an assignment question for a class you might be taking. This is because I have come across an assignment document which describes your question word for word. In this case, I would actually urge you to try to figure out the error on your own as this would help you hone your own skills, [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) are some useful POVs for the same.

As for the answer, I agree with @furas and would provide you with some additional resources that may help in the future.

- Tweepy docs (you can push max_results to 100): https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/v2_pagination.html and https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/client.html#tweepy.Client.search_recent_tweets
- Avoiding RT content (might be useful in the future): [How to Exclude retweets and replies in a search api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27941940/how-to-exclude-retweets-and-replies-in-a-search-api)
- Twitter documentation for building queries: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/search/integrate/build-a-query#operators

Comment: I managed to got it to work. There was a bug with the tweepy package that I had to install. What I needed help with was the error message I was getting, which I didn't even added (very sorry about).